# MySQL Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'discount_advanced_rules'

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, sql-insert

so i have 3 tables which i had to make a single store procedure like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`brambang`@`%` PROCEDURE `create_discount_campaign2`(
    IN discount_campaign_discount_type_id CHAR(22),
    IN discount_campaign_product_id varchar(100),
    IN discount_campaign_marketing_target_id INT,
    IN discount_campaign_max_use_per_user INT,
    IN discount_campaign_discount_code varchar(100),
    IN discout_campaign_discount_amount decimal(10,0),
    IN discount_campaign_start_date datetime,
    IN discount_campaign_end_date datetime,
    IN discount_campaign_min_order_quantity INT,
    IN discount_campaign_min_order_price decimal(10,0),
    IN discount_campaign_discount_quota INT,
    IN discount_campaign_min_product_varian INT,
    IN discount_campaign_apply_all_product INT,
    IN discount_campaign_product_product_id INT,
    IN discount_campaign_product_createdby INT,
    IN discount_campaign_product_updatedby INT,
    IN discount_campaign_product_category_id VARCHAR(100),
    IN discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id INT,
    IN discount_campaign_advanced_value varchar(255),
    IN discount_campaign_advanced_status TINYINT
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE last_id BIGINT;

    INSERT INTO discount_campaigns
    SET
      discount_type_id = discount_campaign_discount_type_id,
      product_id = discount_campaign_product_id,
      marketing_target_id = discount_campaign_marketing_target_id,
      max_use_per_user = discount_campaign_max_use_per_user,
      discount_code = discount_campaign_discount_code,
      discount_amount = discout_campaign_discount_amount,
      start_date = discount_campaign_start_date,
      end_date = discount_campaign_end_date,
      min_order_quantity = discount_campaign_min_order_quantity,
      min_order_price = discount_campaign_min_order_price,
      discount_quota = discount_campaign_discount_quota,
      min_product_variant = discount_campaign_min_product_varian,
      apply_all_products = discount_campaign_apply_all_product,
      createdAt = NOW(),
      updatedAt = NOW();

    IF (discount_campaign_apply_all_product = 0) THEN
        SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO discount_campaign_product (discount_campaign_id,
          product_id, active, createdby, updatedby, createdAt, updatedAt)
        SELECT last_id, c.product_id, case when  
        find_in_set (c.product_id,  discount_campaign_product_product_id) then 0 else 1 end
          discount_campaign_product_createdby, NULL, NOW(), NULL
        FROM product_categories AS c
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.category_id, discount_campaign_product_category_id)
          AND c.status=1;
    END IF;

    SET 
     discount_advanced_rules_id = discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id,
     value = discount_campaign_advanced_value, 
     status = discount_campaign_advanced_status;
    IF (discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO discount_campaign_advanced
        SET 
            discount_campaign_id = last_id,
            discount_advance_rules_id = discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id,
            value = discount_campaign_advanced_value,
            createdAt = NOW(),
            status = discount_campaign_advanced_status;
                END IF;
    
END
```

the problem is in last part which in this part

```
 SET 
     discount_advanced_rules_id = discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id,
     value = discount_campaign_advanced_value, 
     status = discount_campaign_advanced_status;
    IF (discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO discount_campaign_advanced
        SET 
            discount_campaign_id = last_id,
            discount_advance_rules_id = discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id,
            value = discount_campaign_advanced_value,
            createdAt = NOW(),
            status = discount_campaign_advanced_status;
                END IF;
    
END
```

when i run it, it's appear `Error 1193: Unknown system variable 'discount_advanced_rules_id' SQL statement` which part i missed?
this store procedure contain 3 tables which had connected, but on last part, the logic was like this, if `discount_advanced_rules_id` was 0, then the data must insert into `discount_campaign_advanced` table, otherwise, if not, then not insert to that table.

Comment: Are you using @ before the name? Because it's your own variable, not system variable.

Comment: what is the 'name'?

Comment: The variable `discount_advanced_rules_id` is neither declared nor mentioned in input. The only declared variable which's name looks similarly is `IN discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id INT` input parameter.

Comment: did i must have a variable to linked that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
discount_advanced_rules_id
```

is not declared in your code.

You can declare it after the begin:

```
SET @discount_advanced_rules_id = 0;
```

and then you can use it:

```
SET 
     @discount_advanced_rules_id = discount_campaign_advanced_discount_advanced_rules_id,
     value = discount_campaign_advanced_value, 
     status = discount_campaign_advanced_status;
```

The same work with every variable that doesn't comming from your input.
And you need to use @ before the name of the variable.